# Transaction within Batch Write Firebase

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

If I'm doing a batch write of multiple documents, can I do a transaction for each batch?

I want to update multiple documents but want to make sure that the update for each document doesn't overwrite any concurrent updates made by other users.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Firebase documentation on [transactions and batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions):

> There are two types of atomic operations in Cloud Firestore:
>
> Transactions: a transaction is a set of read and write operations on one or more documents.
>
> Batched Writes: a batched write is a set of write operations on one or more documents.

So if a value you need to write depends on an existing value in a document, use a transaction; otherwise use a batched write. You can't mix and match these.

Since you're talking about multiple users potentially overwriting each other's result, it sounds like you need a transaction.

Comment: Right, how would you do a transaction on multiple documents ensuring that it's an all or nothing operation?

The way transactions are written is 1. get the document snapshot 2. perform some logic 3. update that document. So if we want to do a transaction on multiple documents do call a for loop to do a transaction on each document you want to update? But then this doesn't ensure an all or nothing operation...

Or perhaps instead of doing a document snapshot, we do a query snapshot instead?

Comment: Transactions are also atomic, just like batches, and can also write multiple document, just like batches. The only difference is that transactions can also read documents, while batches can only write them.

Comment: Thanks Frank, didn't realize you responded to this thread, I went ahead and deleted my other question.